# otimizar trecho código python

Tags: python

Estou iniciando no mundo do `Python`, escrevi o trecho abaixo e queria a ajuda de vocês para deixá-lo mais eficiente:

```
dforigin = pd.read_csv(client_file_name.csv, sep=';')

total_line_number = len(dforigin.index)

for i, row in dforigin.iterrows(): 
     dforigin.Dia.loc[i] = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(dforigin.Dia[i], 
'%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y%m%d')
```

Esse trecho só foi criado porque eu queria alterar o formato da data no dateframe.

Answer (score 1):

A coluna `Dia` está no formato '%Y-%m-%d'. O primeiro passo é transformar para o tipo data:

```
dforigin.Dia =  pd.to_datetime(dforigin.Dia, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

E depois formatar da maneira que desejar:

```
dforigin.Dia = dforigin.Dia.dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Juntando tudo em um único comando temos:

```
dforigin.Dia =  pd.to_datetime(dforigin.Dia, format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: Noooossa, que diferença!!! Obrigada!